# Совет по реализации иерархии пользователей

Tags: java, дизайн, uml

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать данную идею:

Пишу программу для дипломной работы. На первом этапе хочу создать регистрацию пользователей. Создаю, естественно, бины.

Всего насчитывается 9 ролей; каждый класс - это какой-то пользователей. Причем, их переменные повторяются (имя, email, и еще некоторые). Чтобы не дублировать код, я сделал пока так:

**Предварительная UML диаграмма иерархии пользователей:**
[image]

В самом конструкторе класса делаю так:

```
public class Observer extends User {

@Getter
@Setter
private String firstname;

@Getter
@Setter
private String lastname;

@Getter
@Setter
private Integer age;

public Observer(String email, String password, String firstname, String lastname, Integer age) {
    super.email = email;
    super.password = password;
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.age = age;
}
```

В правильном ли направлении я движусь? Может есть более удобные варианты?

Поделитесь опытом, дабы избежать дублирования кода? Либо, может сделать интерфейсы каждой роли? И как, в таком случае, хранить все в базе данных?

Answer (score 1):

Похоже что вы перепутали пользователей вместе с классами, то же самое для организаций. Возможно вы захотите добавить следующие ассоциации вместо наследования

```
Organization <--- OrganizationType
User <--- UserType
Role <--- User
Role <--- Organization
User <--- Organization
```

Comment: Не совсем Вас понял. Можете поподробнее?

Comment: Что не понятно?